# How do I drag and move an image around inside a Grid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag, grid-layout

How do I drag and move an image around inside a Grid?

Have been trying to solve my problem for days, to no outcome.. here is my code for the xaml.

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="98" Height="500" Width="1010">
        <ContentControl x:Name="poolContainer">                
        </ContentControl>
        <Grid DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" AllowDrop="True">
            <Image Canvas.Left="902" Canvas.Top="324" Height="42" Name="CueStick" Visibility="Visible" Source="/NYP_FYPJ_VP2014;component/Images/cue.png"  Margin="780,230,-92,228"  Drop="CueStick_DragDrop" MouseMove="CueStick_MouseMove" MouseDown="CueStick_MouseDown" MouseUp="CueStick_MouseUp"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <RepeatButton Canvas.Left="1175" Canvas.Top="397" Content="Rotate" Height="23" Name="buttonUp" Width="74" Click="buttonUp_Click" />
</Canvas>
```

Here is my xaml.cs code for the image drag

```
bool drag = false;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
private bool isPictureReadyToDrag;

private void SetPosition()        
{
    CueStick.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - this.Left - CueStick.Width / 2,
    MousePosition.Y - this.Top - CueStick.Height);
}

private void CueStick_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isPictureReadyToDrag)
        SetPosition();
}

private void CueStick_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isPictureReadyToDrag = true;
    SetPosition();
}

private void CueStick_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isPictureReadyToDrag = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong in several places.

The image is put inside a `Grid`, its position is solely controlled by the `Margin` property, `Canvas.Top/Left` do not take effect and you can remove them.

```
<Image Canvas.Left="202" Canvas.Top="324" Margin="780,230,-92,228"
```

and in the code behind, set the image's `Margin` property, not `Location` (there is no such property).

```
CueStick.Margin = new Thickness(...
```

b. Set an explicit Width to the image, because you are using this value in the code behind.

```
<Image Width="229" Height="42"
```

c. You are not using the mouse position correctly; you can get it from `MouseEventArgs`/`MouseButtonEventArgs`, something like

```
private void CueStick_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isPictureReadyToDrag = true;
    double x = e.GetPosition(grid1).X;
    double y = e.GetPosition(grid1).Y;
    SetPosition(x, y);
}

private void SetPosition(double x, double y)
{
    CueStick.Margin = new Thickness(x - CueStick.Width / 2,
    y - CueStick.Height / 2, 0, 0);
}
```

Noted that `grid1` is the containing Grid of the image.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" AllowDrop="True">
    <Image...
```

The hard work of debugging to get the correct `Margin` is left to you.